# Flash won't embed in ie9

Tags: javascript, flash

EDIT: Its the github example code i'm trying to get going in IE9, you have everything you need, i've shown examples of what i've tried, so why down vote me?

I'm using this simple github example code to save some data in a dynamically created popup window.
The flash gets around the security restrictions of saving, works well in Chrome and FireFox.

In IE9 (probably all Ie's) the browser asks to save swfobject.js and then fails.
It's not cross-site, it's not local, but on a regular apache server.

https://github.com/gitbuh/bhd

The code is in the example folder.

I've tried a few things, such as replacing it with the latest `swfobject.js` v2.2

and using an IE friendly doctype and meta, but no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

I'm relatively sure the problem is in the `bhd.js` which does the embedding, and i've played around with the settings, but no luck, here is the code for `bhd.js`:

```
/** BHD

    Browser-Hosted Download
*/
function BHD () {
  return new BHD.Button(opts, callback);
}

BHD.uid = function () {
  return 'x'+(+(''+Math.random()).substring(2)).toString(32)+(+new Date()).toString(32);
};

BHD.getScriptPath = function () {
  if (this.scriptPath) return this.scriptPath;
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for (var i=scripts.length, m; i--;) {
    if ((m=(''+scripts[i].src).match(/(.*\/?)bhd.js(\?|$)/))) {
      return this.scriptPath = m[1] || '';
    }
  }
  return this.scriptPath = '';
}

BHD.include = function (file, callback) {
  var uid = BHD.uid(), frame;
  frame = document.createElement('iframe');
  frame.src = file;
  frame.id = frame.name = uid;
  frame.onload = function () {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    var d = frames[uid].document.documentElement;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.text = d.textContent||d.innerText;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
    callback();
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
    frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
  }
  document.documentElement.appendChild(frame);
}

/** BHD.Button
*/
BHD.Button = function (opts, callback) {

  this.opts = opts;

  if (!opts) return;

  this.setup(opts, callback);

}


/** setup

    Embed the SWF object.

    @param String opts
*/
BHD.Button.prototype.setup = function (opts, callback) {

  var button = this;
  var flashvars = opts;
  var params = { 
    quality: 'high', 
    wmode: 'transparent', 
    swLiveConnect: 'true',
    menu: 'false',
    scale: 'noScale',
    allowFullscreen: 'true',
    allowScriptAccess: 'always'
  };
  var attributes = { id: opts.id, name: opts.id };

  this.opts = opts;

  opts.callbackName = BHD.uid();

  window[opts.callbackName] = callback;

  window[opts.callbackName + '_resize'] = function(w, h){
    object = button.getElement();
    object.style.width = w + 'px';
    object.style.height = h + 'px';
  };

  var cb = function(){
    swfobject.embedSWF(BHD.getScriptPath() + 'bhd.swf', 
        opts.id, '1', '1', '9.0.0', 
        null, flashvars, params, attributes);
  }

  if (typeof swfobject == 'undefined') {
    BHD.include(BHD.getScriptPath() + 'swfobject.js', cb);
  } else {
    cb();
  }

};


/** getElement

    Get the embedded flash element, or element to be replaced
    if swfobject.embedSWF has not finished yet.

    @param String variable
    @param Mixed value 
*/
BHD.Button.prototype.getElement = function () {
  return document.getElementById(this.opts.id);
};

/** setFile

    Set the default filename to show in the save dialog.

    @param String value 
*/
BHD.Button.prototype.setFile = function (value) {
  return this.getElement().setFile(value);
};

/** setData

    Set the contents of the download file.

    @param Mixed value 
*/
BHD.Button.prototype.setData = function (value) {
  return this.getElement().setData(value);
};

/** setUrl

    Set the URL of the download file.

    @param Mixed value 
*/
BHD.Button.prototype.setUrl = function (value) {
  return this.getElement().setUrl(value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `bhd.js` script won't bootstrap `swfobject.js` properly in IE9.
Adding this line to `example/index.html` above line 4, fixes the problem for IE9.

```
<script src="../dist/swfobject.js"></script>
```

Confirmed same problem in IE 10, this fix works as well.